# Revoke app permissions from facebook programmatically

Tags: android, permissions, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on an android app which takes a screenshot in a specific activity and posts it on Facebook for the user (FacebookSDK).

First time, it asks the user for the permissions, asks to login and specify the view(Public, Friends.. etc). When next time again when the activity is called it says like "You have already authorized App" and straight way posts the pic after clicking ok.

Problem is:

1. The picture is being posted as second picture of the previous post. I intend to post it as an independent second post.
2. No permissions or view was asked second time. I intend to ask for permission and view every-time the post is made.

Please help.

Code:

```
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

            //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
            manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
            manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
            manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    shareOnFacebook();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(HallOfFame.this, "Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(HallOfFame.this, "Error Occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return true;
```

The method shareOnFacebook:

```
// Take Screenshot
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();;
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
    //**Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setCaption("Hey Guys..! Checkout my Awesome Pic.")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    ShareApi.share(content, null);
    manager.logOut();
    //        this.finish();
    //        this.onDestroy();
    //        FacebookSdk.clearLoggingBehaviors();
```